# Example of sequence that tends to infinity but had sub sequence which is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis

I am finding sequence which tends to infinity but has some Cauchy sub sequence.
Is for that {1,0,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,..} correct example?

Is unbounded means sequence tends to either Positive infinity or negative infinity?

Thanks in Advanced .

I am new at this topic ,Any Help will be appreciated .

Comment: This sequence is unbounded, but as it contains a Cauchy subsequence, it does not diverge to eiher $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Recall that this would require $a_n>M$ for all $n>N$ for some $N$ depending on $M$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen  Sir Why this is not divergent to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to have a sequence that tends to $+\infty$ and has a Cauchy subsequence. To tend to infinity means that for all $M>0$ there is some $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n|>M$ for all $n>n_0$. On the other hand the Cauchy subsequence must converge at some real number lets say $\alpha$. Then for $M=|\alpha | +1$ the terms of the subsequence will never get greater than $M$. So the sequence cannot tend to infinity. The next best is to be unbounded and have a Cauchy subsequence. The example you give is like that

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use the term diverge. What I mean is the limit of the sequence is $+\infty$, or that the sequence tends to $+\infty$